# Blurry text on CSS rotated element in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rotatetransform

I have created a hexagon using CSS, the hexagon has a rollover state, with text in it, which always appears blurry in chrome, but looks fine in IE11, IE Edge and FF.

Due to the hexagon being made from CSS, I can't remove the rotation on the elements, so I need another way to fix the text being blurry?

I have an example here, I've also tried using the following CSS attributes but none of them seem to stop the text being fuzzy:

https://jsfiddle.net/zg0eprmu/8/

```
-webkit-filter: blur;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
will-change: transform;
-webkit-perspective: 1000px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform-origin(50% 51%);
```

Comment: This is actually a known issue for webkit browser, I think your best solution is to remove all the transforms and create 4 triangle elements and position them on each corner.

Comment: Or another solution I could think of is move your text out and place in another div so it doesn't interfere with the transform